# Missing definitions in Azure Developer Portal

Tags: swagger, azure-api-management, azure-api-apps

I am developing some APIs and Swagger is showing correctly all the related info, definitions included:

[image]

But when the API is published into Azure Developer Portal some definitions are not shown. I mean, the link is visible but it doesn't do anything

[image]

This happen only for some APIs.

Does anyone know is this is something I have misconfigured?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's an open issue on GitHub:
https://github.com/Azure/api-management-developer-portal/issues/1889

> When I navigate through the different objects defined in my yaml via Developer Portal some links don't work because some of them are not loaded.
> For instance in next screenshot you can see an outboundInvoice object but in the developer portal the link to it doesn't work.
> I've even added a "definitions" object (you also can see it in that screenshot) that explicitly references all objects used but has made no difference.
> I have the feeling it has to do with inheritance: when there's no inheritance objects look to load correctly. But I might be wrong.

[image]

[image]